# Angular ng-show doesnt work from the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to display a div after a video finishes. The alert shows up after the video finish but the div is still not visible.What am I doing wrong.
Thank you for the help in advance.

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/App/Controllers/TestController.js"></script>
}
<div ng-controller="TestController as ctrl" class="md-content" ng-cloak>
    <h1>Test</h1>

    <video id="myVideo"  controls autoplay>
        <source src="~/Videos/Test1.mp4">
    </video>

    <div id="test" ng-show="ui.showTest">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        Added this as a test to see if your controller is linked to the view
        <p>{{ui.shouldSeeThis}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the controller

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
.controller('TestController', function ($scope, $http, $filter, $mdDialog) {


var vid;

function initializePlayer() {

    vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    vid.addEventListener('ended', videoFinish, false);
}

window.onload = initializePlayer;

$scope.ui = {
    showTest: false,
    //I've added this to see if your controller is linked to the view
    shouldSeeThis: "Hello World"
};
function videoFinish() {
    $scope.ui.showTest = true;
    alert("VideoFinish");
}
```

});

Comment: there isn't enough information here to know for sure what the problem is, but you are *probably* victim of the "always use a dot in angular bindings" rule.  you have bound a primitive in the `ng-show`, and it is very easy for this primitive to be inaccessible due to prototype inheritance.  You should always bind object properties, not primitives.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs

Comment: you should provide the entire code.

Comment: you do check what is the value of showTest after the video. $scope is not unique... you can have a problem with another $scope, for that you can write {{showTest}} or install a extencion how ng-inspector. a easy fix is use a object

Comment: this might be a case were you need to trigger a digest cycle with either $timeout or $scope.apply. Not the best solution but yet some times is needed

Comment: you defined "TestController as ctrl" but used ng-show="ui.showTest". Try to use ctrl.showTest on ng-show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you need to force digest in order to reflect scope changes in the view. This happens because you are changing the scope value using a javascript event.

In your controller add `$timeout`:

```
.controller('TestController', function ($scope, $http, $filter, $mdDialog, $timeout)
```

In your function wrap the code with it:

```
function videoFinish() {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.ui.showTest = true;
      alert("VideoFinish");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, it's best practice to bind to an object property. Try the following:

```
<div id="test" ng-show="ui.showTest">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <!-- Added this as a test to see if your controller is linked to the view-->
    <p>{{ui.shouldSeeThis}}</p>
</div>
```

---

```
$scope.ui = {
    showTest: false,
    //I've added this to see if your controller is linked to the view
    shouldSeeThis: "Hello World"
};
function videoFinish()
{
    $scope.ui.showTest = true;
    alert("VideoFinish");
}
```

As the comments state, I've added an extra property to the object, if you paste the code above you should see "Hello World" inside the `<p>` element. I placed this in the answer as your question does not provide all of the relevant code.

Comment: Thank you. I modified my code according to your suggestions but I still don't see my div